# Update Google play existing(eclipse) APK with android studio new APK

Tags: android, google-play

I have to update my google play existing apk with newly created android studio apk
I have existing keystore with me,but i dont know how do i use it..

Answer (score 3):

In AndroidStudio click on Build -> Generate Signed apk

[image]

[image]

Add your keystore details and build

Answer (score 1):

Click on Build → Create Signed APK → Input path to keystore and passwords → Build